# Echo an embedded YouTube video from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, xampp

I'm trying to echo a YouTube embedded video using my database.
But I can't figure out where my error is..

Config.php file:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

And here I'm trying to echo the YouTube video:

```
include ("/includes/config.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$row['video']."' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

In the echo part, I'm echoing $row['video'], video is the code from the YouTube video that every video has.

But it still doesn't work, someone can help me out please?

Comment: What happens when you run your code? An error? A blank screen? Does it print the wrong thing? What does your generated iframe look like?

Comment: You might also want to paste the page source.

Comment: @andrewsi it doesn't do anything, it stays blank.

Comment: @NishchalGautam You don't need it to solve this ;)

Comment: @Jesse - I'm guessing that your `include ("/includes/config.php");` is wrong - that's looking for a file in an `/includes/` directory right at the root of the server, rather than in a subdirectory. Maybe try `include ("includes/config.php");` without the initial `/`?

Comment: How are you testing if there is error on your php code? just paste the output of the script and check if it's working as expected.

Comment: can you please write anything before the while loop something like `echo 'hello world'; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` just to be sure the code is running

Comment: @robert I did that, I think the problem is in the while loop, since it does echo outside the while loop..

Comment: can you please put this code at the top of the script `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
` to display error ( if there ) for you

Comment: and change `include ("/includes/config.php");` to `require ("/includes/config.php");` with keeping the `echo 'hello world';` after the `require` just in case

Answer (score 0):

1.Check your browser source code whether it is printing code correctly.

2.Check that you are printing the video code only looks like this`(h1h4hdj6)` after `https://www.youtube.com/embed/`